# How to get grouped boxplots with vertical subplots

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I'm trying to create a chart like the one in this image using Plotly.js:
[image]

It's a grouped boxplot (by sites, currently only one) with two y axes.

I've managed to create two versions, both of which don't work:

1. Create 5 traces (1 for each box) so that you can define the correct y axis for each box. This then puts them all next to each other, because they're different traces.
2. Create 3 traces to represent A, B and C. But then (afaik) I have to pick one y axis for each, which means that I can't have the same trace on two y axes.

Here's the code from approach 1 (https://codepen.io/wacmemphis/pen/gJQJeO?editors=0010)

```
var data =[  
  {  
    "x":[  
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1"
    ],
    "xaxis":"x",
    "yaxis":"y",
    "name":"A",
    "type":"box",
    "boxpoints":false,
    "y":[  
      "3.81",
      "3.74",
      "3.62",
      "3.50",
      "3.50",
      "3.54"
    ]
  },
  {  
    "x":[  
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1"
    ],
    "xaxis":"x",
    "yaxis":"y",
    "name":"B",
    "type":"box",
    "boxpoints":false,
    "y":[  
      "1.54",
      "1.54",
      "1.60",
      "1.41",
      "1.65",
      "1.47"
    ]
  },
  {  
    "x":[  
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1"
    ],
    "xaxis":"x",
    "yaxis":"y",
    "name":"C",
    "type":"box",
    "boxpoints":false,
    "y":[  
      "3.31",
      "3.81",
      "3.74",
      "3.63",
      "3.76",
      "3.68"
    ]
  },
  {  
    "x":[  
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1"
    ],
    "xaxis":"x2",
    "yaxis":"y2",
    "name":"A",
    "type":"box",
    "boxpoints":false,
    "y":[  
      "3.81",
      "3.74",
      "3.62",
      "3.50",
      "3.50",
      "3.54"
    ]
  },
  {  
    "x":[  
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1",
      "Site 1"
    ],
    "xaxis":"x2",
    "yaxis":"y2",
    "name":"C",
    "type":"box",
    "boxpoints":false,
    "y":[  
      "3.31",
      "3.81",
      "3.74",
      "3.63",
      "3.76",
      "3.68"
    ]
  }
];

var layout = {
  yaxis: {
     domain: [0, 0.5],
    title: 'axis 1',
  },
    yaxis2: {
      domain: [0.5, 1],
      title: 'axis2',
    },
  boxmode: 'group'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Two questions on that: Is it required to use only one chart with two axis or are two charts okay, too? Is autorange the required range method or are the ranges in the displayed images fixed to those values?

Comment: @Jankapunkt It could also be two charts, but the individual traces should be in the same place with the same color. In some charts a trace might not exist at all (orange in the first part in the screenshot above).

Comment: This is possible but the question remains, whether you know certain ranges or if you are totally blind about the possible ranges of the data (what I assume, since you used `domain` instead of `range`). Maybe you can add some little detail on the possible variations of the data and why you chose the two domains (0 - 0.5 and 0.5 - 1)

Comment: @Jankapunkt The way I understood it, the 0-0.5 and 0.5-1 are only to determine the height proportion of each individual y-axis, but I may have gotten that wrong. I don't know the value ranges until I get the data and reformat it into the traces.

Comment: This is why I asked about possible thresholds because how would you determine, that data with `name: "B"` will be part of `yaxis` but not of `yaxis2` ? Of course you just manually omitted in in your example but this will not work when throwing in arbitrary data, where autorange will consider all the data to be displayed and domain will consider all the data for scaling. I can provide you an example that works, if you could determine a range (or any other threshold criteria to omit `B` in the upper axis) for the two axis.

Comment: @Jankapunkt When I receive the data from the server, I can determine whether it needs to go to `yaxis` or `yaxis2` (or even `yaxis3` and so on) based on an attribute in the data. I then split it into the `data` object you see in the example. If you can create an example that looks like what I need, I could then most likely convert my original data into that format. At the moment I'm not able to get the chart that I need even with fixed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

First of all I would like to emphasize that this is rather a **workaraound**, because  Plotly currently does not support to distribute a single data source to multiple axis without interpreting them as new trace-instances (although it would be great to just set an array of target axis like `{ yaxis: [ "y", "y2" ] }`).

However, Plotly is very deterministic in the way it handles ordering and grouping of traces, which can be taken to our advantage.

The following workaround approaches the problem in the following way:

- 1. Use two charts with one xaxis/yaxis instead of two axes
- 2. Use a single source of data for each trace (`A`, `B`, `C`)
- 3. Add traces to each (or both) of the plots dynamically, based on external decision
- 4. Use one of the following tactics to insert ghost objects and thus keep traces of both plots on the same x-axis positions:

     - a) use opacity
     - b) use a minimal width
     - c) use a threshold

#### 1. Use two charts instead of two axes

Let's assume we can use two charts with the same layout:

```html
<head>
    <!-- Plotly.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
   <!-- render the upper axis 2 chart -->
   <div id="myDiv_upper"></div>

   <!-- render the lower axis 1 chart --> 
    <div id="myDiv_lower"></div>

    <script>
        /* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
   </script>
</body>
```

With the accompanying js code to create two inital empty charts with the given layouts:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv_lower");
const myDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDiv_upper");

const layout = {
    yaxis: {
        domain: [0, 0.5],
        title: "axis 1",
        constrain: "range"
    },
    margin: {
        t: 0,
        b: 0,
        pad: 0
    },
    showlegend: false,
    boxmode: "group"
};

const layout2 = {
    yaxis: {
        domain: [ 0.5, 1 ],
        title: "axis 2",
    },
    xaxis: {
        domain: [ 0, 1 ]
    },
   margin: {
        t: 0,
        b: 0,
        pad: 0
    },
    boxmode: "group"
};

Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, [], layout);
Plotly.newPlot(myDiv2, [], layout2);
```

The resulting empty plot will look like this, if no further data is added:

[image]

#### 2. Use a single source of data for each trace (`A`, `B`, `C`)

We can then split the data into three main source-objects:

```
const A = {
    x: ["Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1"],
    xaxis: "x",
    yaxis: "y",
    name: "A",
    legendgroup: "A",
    type: "box",
    boxpoints: false,
    y: ["3.81", "3.74", "3.62", "3.50", "3.50", "3.54"]
};

const B = {
    x: ["Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1"],
    xaxis: "x",
    yaxis: "y",
    name: "B",
    legendgroup: "B",
    type: "box",
    boxpoints: false,
    y: ["1.54", "1.54", "1.60", "1.41", "1.65", "1.47"]
};

const C = {
    x: ["Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1"],
    xaxis: "x",
    yaxis: "y",
    name: "C",
    legendgroup: "C",
    type: "box",
    boxpoints: false,
    y: ["3.31", "3.81", "3.74", "3.63", "3.76", "3.68"]
}
```

#### 3. Add traces to each (or both) of the plots dynamically, based on external decision

First of all we create a helper `add`, that updates the charts, based on new incoming data and one that creates our ghost object helper, named `placeholder`:

```js
const placeholder = src => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, src)
    // use one of the strategies here to make this a ghost object
    return copy
}

const add = ({ src, y1, y2 }) => {
    let src2
    if (y1 && y2) {
        Plotly.addTraces(myDiv, [src])
        Plotly.addTraces(myDiv2, [src])
    } else if (y1 && !y2) {
        src2 = placeholder(src)
        Plotly.addTraces(myDiv, [src])
        Plotly.addTraces(myDiv2, [src2])
    } else if (!y1 && y2) {
       src2 = placeholder(src)
       Plotly.addTraces(myDiv, [src2])
        Plotly.addTraces(myDiv2, [src])
   } else {
        throw new Error('require either y1 or y2 to be true to add data')
    }
}
```

Based on the given images the decisions to add the data to the axis would result in the following calls:

```js
add({ src: A, y1: true, y2: true })
add({ src: B, y1: true, y2: false })
add({ src: C, y1: true, y2: true })
```

This would create the following (yet not satisfiable) result:

[image]

Now we have at least resolved the grouping and color. The next step is to look for possible ways of making `B` a ghost object, that requires spacing in the upper chart but won't display the data.

#### 4. Use one of the following tactics to insert ghost objects and thus keep traces of both plots on the same x-axis positions

Before we look into the different options, let's see what happens, if we remove the data or null the data.

**remove the data**

Removing the data would mean, that the `placeholder` has no x/y values:

```js
const placeholder = src => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, src)
    delete copy.x
    delete copy.y
    return copy
}
```

The result would still not satisfy the requirements:

[image]

**null the data**

Nulling the data has the nice effect, that the data is added to the legend (which has basically the same effect as `visible: 'legendonly'`:

```js
const placeholder = src => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, src)
    copy.x = [null]
    copy.y = [null]
    return copy
}
```

The result would still not satisfy the requirements, allthough at least the legend grouping is now correct:

[image]

**a) use opacity**

One option to create a ghost object is to set it's opacity to zero:

```js
const placeholder = src => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, src)
    copy.opacity = 0
    copy.hoverinfo = "none" // use "name" to show "B"
    return copy
}
```

The result has the advantage, that it pleaces the objects in the right positions. A big disadvantage is, that the legend's opactiy for B is bound to the object's opacity and this shows only the label `B` but not the colored box.

Another disadvantage is that the data of `B` still affects the `yaxis` scaling:

[image]

**b) use a minimal width**

Using a minimal amount greater zero causes the trace to nearly disappear, while a small line remains.

```js
const placeholder = src => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, src)
    copy.width = 0.000000001
    copy.hoverinfo = "none" // or use "name"
    return copy
}
```

This example keeps the grouping, positioning and legend correct but the scaling is still affected and the remaining line can be misinterpreted (which can be very problematic IMO):

[image]

**c) use a threshold**

Now this is the only solution that satisfies all the requirements with a great caveit: it requires a `range` to be set on the yaxis:

```js
const layout2 = {
    yaxis: {
        domain: [ 0.5, 1 ],
        title: "axis 2",
        range: [3.4, 4] // this is hardcoded for now
    },
    xaxis: {
        domain: [ 0, 1 ]
    },
   margin: {
        t: 0,
        b: 0,
        pad: 0
    },
    boxmode: "group"
}

// ...

// with ranges we can safely add 
// data to both charts, because they
// get ghosted, based on their fit 
// within / outside the range
const add = ({ src }) => {
    Plotly.addTraces(myDiv, [src])
    Plotly.addTraces(myDiv2, [src])
}

add({ src: A })
add({ src: B })
add({ src: C })
```

The result will then look like the following:

[image]

Now the only question remains, how to determin the range after the new data has been added? Fortunately Plotly provides a function to update the layout, named `Plotly.relayout`.

For this example we may choose a simple anchor, like the mean. Of course any other method to determine the range is possible.

```js
const add = ({ src }) => {
    Plotly.addTraces(myDiv, [src])
    Plotly.addTraces(myDiv2, [src])
    return src.y
}

// add the data and generate a sum of all values
const avalues = add({ src: A })
const bvalues = add({ src: B })
const cvalues = add({ src: C })
const allValues = [].concat(avalues, bvalues, cvalues)

// some reusable helpers to determine our range
const highest = arr => Math.max.apply( Math, arr )
const mean = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0) / arr.length

const upperRange = highest(allValues)  // 3.81
const meanRange = mean(allValues)      // 2.9361111111111113

// our new values to update the upper layour
const updatedLayout = {
    yaxis: {
        range: [meanRange, upperRange]
    }
}

Plotly.relayout(myDiv2, updatedLayout)
```

The resulting graph looks mostly like the desired result:

[image]

You can use this link to play around and improve it at your wish: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agzKBV?editors=1010

#### Summary

This example is still to be considered a workaround and is not tested beyond the given data. There is also room for improvement regarding the reusability and code efficiency and it is all written down in a sequencial manner to make this code understandable as possible.

Please also keep in mind, that displaying the same data on two different axis can be misleading to be interpreted as two different sets of data.

Any suggestions for improvement are allowed, code is free to use.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely detailed answer! It's shown me a few different options that I can now go and investigate. Thanks again!